# I cant identify the cause of a weird CSS behavior on Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

I'm a budding junior dev, and I've been putting together my first portfolio. I'm slowly getting ready for a final version to put together and upload, and for test purposes I've uploaded a WIP version of it on my shared host service.
However I'm faced with a weird issue :
Upon checking how the page behaved on different browsers ( Chrome, Opera, Edge and Firefox ) the page seemed fine, until i checked it with Mozilla Firefox.

I've been trying to figure out why, but on Firefox and Firefox only, the site seems to have a void that extends to the right of the page past any elements. I checked the console to see which element could be causing it, and while i found one element with an initial width that could be the cause, adjusting its width changed nothing.

I don't want to write it off as " its just a Firefox thing " and its the first time i see this behavior, and specifically the fact that its purely happening on that browser.

The element that i could see as the cause could be the project-container `div` element:

```css
*, ::before, ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.BackgroundImage {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
}

.BackgroundImage img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.project-container {
  min-width: 80%;
  position: relative;
  right: 85%;
}
```

```html
<div class="BackgroundImage">
  <img alt="" src="https://personalfolio.apoillot.fr/storage/images/Homeimage.jpg">
  <div class="project-container">(whatever)</div>
</div>
```

You can check the page on different browsers at the following address, so you can see the difference between what happens on Firefox and other browsers: https://personalfolio.apoillot.fr/home
I'd appreciate any help that'd allow me identify and correct the problem, I really can't figure it out for myself...

Comment: As a workaround, you can add `overflow-x: hidden;` into `.BackgroundImage`. This should eliminate the extra horizontal spacing that was caused by the `.project-container`. I came up with it because I don't see the website utilize horizontal scrolling for the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Firefox allocates space for the second flex "cell" (`.project-container`) that you then are pulling back using position and leaves that allocated space there.

In context of your layout, it does not make much sense to do so; your `.BackgroundImage` wrapper should probably not be `flex` container in the first place.

To be honest, I am not completely sure if Firefox seemingly buggy behaviour is not in fact correct here, so filed a [WebCompat issue](https://webcompat.com/issues/129041) ([GH](https://github.com/webcompat/web-bugs/issues/129041)) to find out.

MRE with flex: only Firefox produces scrollbar for allocated space:

```css
.wrap {
  border: solid red;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.flex__full {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.flex__abs {
  background-color: maroon;
  min-width: 50px;
  position: relative;
  right: 60px;
}

html {
  color-scheme: dark;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="flex__full">a</div>
    <div class="flex__abs">b</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Firefox: [image: Wrapper with red border shows scrollbar, scrolled to the rightmost end there is visible vacant space after blue "full" container.]

Edge: [image: Wrapper with red border does not show any scrollbar, blue "full" container occupies its entire inner width.]

MRE with non-wrapping inline-blocks: same outcome in Firefox and Chrome (Edge):

```css
.wrap {
 border: solid red;
 overflow: auto;
 position: relative;
 width: 200px;
 text-align: center;
 white-space: nowrap;
}

span { display: inline-block;}
.full {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.abs {
  background-color: maroon;
  min-width: 50px;
  position: relative;
  right: 60px;
}

html { color-scheme: dark; }
```

```html
<div class="wrap"
 ><span class="full">a</span
 ><span class="abs">b</span
></div>
```

Firefox: [image: Wrapper with red border shows scrollbar, scrolled to the rightmost end there is visible vacant space after blue "full" container.]

Edge: [image: Wrapper with red border shows scrollbar, scrolled to the rightmost end there is visible vacant space after blue "full" container.]

---

Alternative approach for original design (background image of absolutely positioned pseudo element):

```css
html {
 color-scheme: dark;
 background-color: black;
 color: white;
 position: relative;
}
body {
 margin: 0;
 min-height: 100vh;
 padding: 1em;
}
html::before {
 content: '';
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 height: 100%;
 min-height: 100vh;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: -1;
 background-image: url('https://personalfolio.apoillot.fr/storage/images/Homeimage.jpg');
 background-size: cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: top center;
 animation: 2s bg;
}
@keyframes bg {
 from {opacity: 0; }
 to { opacity: 1; }
}
div {
 width: 30ch;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 10ch auto 30ch;
 background-color: tan;
 color: black;
 padding: 3ch;
}
```

```html
<div>(whatever)</div>
<div>(whatever)</div>
<div>(whatever)</div>
```

Comment: I've tried the solution you proposed ( globally adding the box-sizing ) but it didnt seem to fix the issue, i also made sure to match exactly the other properties ( aka removing the other elements of the other properties ) while keeping the global box sizing, but this also didnt seem to do the trick :/

Comment: I haven't proposed that `box-sizing` affects it in any way, it was just part of your own app/bootstrap (https://personalfolio.apoillot.fr/build/assets/app-03e6b848.css) CSS that generally affects MRE, but in fact could be omitted as well, so my bad including it there.

Comment: What I would propose is to ditch `display: flex` on the wrapper and make the background `img` "underlay" absolutely positioned instead. Or even better, use real `background-image` and do the fade animation with fading "mask" gradient in higher `background-image` layer.

Comment: I'm obviously not the best in CSS, my reasoning for not using absolute for the background-image was that on another page, where i add projects, i'm looking for an effect where as you keep scrolling down ( without pagination) the background image is still present, from memory, doing so with the background image on absolute would not achieve the result. As for the mask method, i admit i've no idea what it is to be completely honest